# Use custom "Loading..." div for Fancybox 2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I search for this but did not find a solution or any mention in the docs at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/:

Is it possible to use my own `div` instead of the loader GIF while Fancybox is waiting for the content (ajax request)?

Comment: Maybe check this thread - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the CSS styles which are currently set to this

```
#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

and add your own image, size, background-color etc.
However to actually override the content in terms of adding in extra elements etc. you are going to have to amend the fancybox library to do that.

**Update**

In view of your comment making the question somewhat clearer,
You can override the fancybox library without touching the library itself.
Below is an example of an override:

```
var loadingExtension ={
    oldShowLoading: $.fancybox.showLoading,
    showLoading: function(){
        // You can still call the old loader here below if you want and then manipulate the DOM or you can make your own custom code.
        //this.oldShowLoading();
        // custom code

    } 
};
$.extend($.fancybox, loadingExtension);
```

Below is the original `showLoading()` method

```
showLoading: function () {
        var el, viewport;

        F.hideLoading();

        el = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>').click(F.cancel).appendTo('body');

        // If user will press the escape-button, the request will be canceled
        D.bind('keydown.loading', function(e) {
            if ((e.which || e.keyCode) === 27) {
                e.preventDefault();

                F.cancel();
            }
        });

        if (!F.defaults.fixed) {
            viewport = F.getViewport();

            el.css({
                position : 'absolute',
                top  : (viewport.h * 0.5) + viewport.y,
                left : (viewport.w * 0.5) + viewport.x
            });
        }

        F.trigger('onLoading');
    },
```

The most crucial line here is el = `$('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>').click(F.cancel).appendTo('body');` Which you can change, but then remember there will be a corresponding `hideLoading()` method which currently looks like this.

```
hideLoading: function () {
D.unbind('.loading');

$('#fancybox-loading').remove();
},
```

Which you would also want to amend in the override depending on your new contents in-place of the loading `<div>`

An complete example of the override with the above in mind would be as below.  You would include this after the library itself but before any other custom JS.  Note that I have copied some of the references from elsewhere in the fancybox library such as the `H, W, D, F` variables as they are used throughout for brevity.

```
loadingExtension = {
    oldShowLoading: $.fancybox.showLoading,
    oldHideLoading: $.fancybox.hideLoading,
    showLoading: function () {
        H = $("html");
        W = $(window);
        D = $(document);
        F = $.fancybox;
        var el, viewport;

        F.hideLoading();
        el = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div>testing!</div></div>').click(F.cancel).appendTo('body');

        // If user will press the escape-button, the request will be canceled
        D.bind('keydown.loading', function (e) {
            if ((e.which || e.keyCode) === 27) {
                e.preventDefault();

                F.cancel();
            }
        });

        if (!F.defaults.fixed) {
            viewport = F.getViewport();

            el.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: (viewport.h * 0.5) + viewport.y,
                left: (viewport.w * 0.5) + viewport.x
            });
        }

        F.trigger('onLoading');
    },
    hideLoading: function () {
        $(document).unbind('.loading');
        $('#fancybox-loading').remove();
    }

};
$.extend($.fancybox, loadingExtension);
```

Hope that's clear enough.  Here's a fiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/aBCL5/, I've only used the first few images and changed some to make the load take longer.
Let me know if you have any troubles.
R.

Comment: Your extension looks like exactly what I want - will try it out tomorrow and report back...

Comment: I finally went with bPopup because of the better license and I do not need the additional functionality, but thanks anyway - I probably still need this for another part of my page...